# Code inside for loop working only after the loop is completed

Tags: c#

I have a function called **ExecuteLoop** as

```
private void ExecuteLoop()
{ 
 for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
 lable1.Text=i;
}
```

but the label text is not changing..At the end of the loop its showing like "10000"

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using winforms? The winforms controls hide a lot of detail about what's really going on. At a lower level, your program will rely on code in the .Net framework that looks something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    var message = GetMessagesFromOperatingSystem();
    HandleReceivedMessage(message);
    if (message == WM_QUIT) return;
}
```

This is called the message pump or message loop. That's not the real code, but it should give you the idea.

When you change a label text, or set any other property on a control, the setter for that property calls a function which tells the operating system that the screen space allocated for your control is now invalid, and needs to be re-drawn. Windows will then post a message back to your program that it needs to redraw that space. This message is received by the code demonstrated above, and *that code is in the same thread as your `for` loop.* The net result of all this is that no changes to your control properties will be shown on the screen until the method ends.

There are a few ways around this. The best one for your situation will depend on what you're really trying to do. As quick examples, if you're trying to show a clock you'll likely want to use a timer component, and move your code to the timer's `tick` event, rather than use a delay in a loop. If this is a placeholder for more complicated work that will be added in later, you probably want to use a BackgroundWorker component (though it will see overkill at first for something so simple).

Comment: +1 For the mention of a `BackgroundWorker` because from the comments it sounds like that is what the OP is going to need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please submit the code for my problem as mentioned above?

Comment: @bageesh from your comments it sounds like you'll be needing a `BackgroundWorker` and a `ProgressBar`. Your exact implementation of them will depend on your specific needs, making it difficult to really submit code. I'd recommend you start by reading up on background workers and threading on MSDN.

Comment: @bageesh : i support with Leon you need background worker here.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger I have tried that.But when i am using that it loads corrupted data into my spread

Comment: @bageesh Well that is an all together different problem with a different solution. There are many things that could be going on to cause that issue. Should you decide that's the route you need to go I would recommend posting that code and a new question.

Comment: Ok. So there is no other way to solve this issue other than background worker

Comment: There's always DoEvents()... but you don't want to go there.

Comment: ya.. i heard about `delegate` and `BeginInvoke`, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

it does not show the intermediate values as you are not adding delay in between use `Timer` to see the `Label` `Text` changing from `0 to 10000`.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       int count = 0;
       int maxlimit=10000;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            SetTimer(500);
        }
        private void SetTimer(int milliseconds)
        {            
            timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(Object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (count < maxlimit)
            {
                label1.Text = count.ToString();
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                label1.Text = "completed!";
                timer1.Stop();

            }
        }
```

Comment: its just the sample code.Actually in my for loop I am reading date from an excel file into a spread.It will take some minutes to complete..so I need to alert the user that the software is still working.So that i am changing the label with the data read from excel.

Comment: Thank you for your support..I need to change the text in the loop itself..Could you please suggest a solution for that